# Python sending files over scp using pexpect

Tags: python, operating-system, scp, pexpect, torrent

So I'm trying to send all my torrent files to a server with scp using pexpect.  This works for the most part but not all my torrent files get sent.  Even though the print function in 'if i==0' prints out all the torrents.  And if I go to the server and delete everything that got sent and run it again, the same torrent files get sent.  Does anyone know what the problem might be?

```
import os
import getpass
import subprocess
import pexpect

filepath = 'my downloads dir'

os.chdir(filepath)

var_password = str(getpass.getpass())
destination = "user@server:dir"

for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.torrent'):
        try:
            var_command = "scp " + filepath + filename + " " + destination

            var_child = pexpect.spawn(var_command)
            i = var_child.expect(["password:", pexpect.EOF])

            if i==0: # send password            
                print('Sending: ' + filename)    
                var_child.sendline(var_password)
                var_child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
            elif i==1: 
                print("Got the key or connection timeout")
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            print("Oops Something went wrong buddy")
            print(e)
```

Comment: Why not create an archive of `*.torrent` files and then send it with `scp` ? 
Also, where is the scp command in your script ? `var_command` ?

Comment: What is var_command? Also, you could be timing out the connection or perhaps sending files that have a non compatible character/space in them for the server.

Comment: here it is, sorry I deleted it when refactoring the code.  But I'm trying to get this to work as it will be a part of larger system

Comment: I would compress files anyway, send it to destination server and then extract them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, thanks to David's comment.  The files that include spaces and icelandic letters (since I'm icelandic) don't get transferred.

Comment: Given your username I had guessed you were Swedish.  Right hemisphere at least.